# My TextView is disappearing when I apply an email autolink attribute to it

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I am attempting to make a textview clickable by adding an email autolink attribute to it with `android:autoLink="email"`but as soon as I add it, the text just disappears. What's interesting is that other combinations of text appear just fine. When typing in an email, as soon as I type the "o" in sample@gmail.com, the text just disappears. Am I doing something wrong?

My TextView

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="sample@gmail.com"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:textColor="#54ACE6"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
```

Comment: I can only see  two mistakes in this, but I don't think these mistakes causing the error. One is clickable="true" is not required if there is autLink mentioned. and While setting textSize use sp instead of dp.

Comment: And are you getting this error in preview section or in emulator/real device?

Comment: The text doesn't show in either the preview or the emulator. As soon as I get to the "o" is disappears. I can't fathom why. I was able to remedy it by just placing a textview over top of it with the same text but not linked so when they click it, it's actually clicking the email link beneath it.

Comment: Please provide your layout xml code. (i.e. activity_main.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set android:textColorLink="@color/blue" or any other color different than your background.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).